# Represent a time with no date in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

Is there a way to represent a time in ruby without having a Date attached? I am doing a timetracking application and I only need in/out times, there is a separate column for date.

The MySQL TIME data type stores only the time, but in Rails it comes back as Jan 1 2000 + what ever time is there.

Should i just ignore the date part, or is there a way to eliminate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to eliminate it, [because](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html):

> Time is stored internally as the number of seconds with fraction since the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC.

Just format it like this:

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")
```

Comment: I know i can format it like that, I'm more worried about subtraction and having two different dates.

Comment: You'll just have to handle it manually using t.hour, t.min, t.sec etc. depending on your accuracy requirements. What happens when the in time is 23:00 and the out time is 01:00?

Comment: if that  ever happens they can enter two entries, No body here works those hours, so its not an issue right now. But yeah, alas i was hoping it would just natively support that.

Comment: Yes, Ruby's Time store the seconds, so I am looking for a Class which stores only hours,minutes and seconds (I would call it TimeSpan )
so that i can query:
   ` WorkLog.where("workduration > ?", TimeSpan.new(8,30,0) ) `

Answer (score 46):

We just store times with no attached dates as minutes since midnight in an integer column (that's Postgres not MySQL but nonetheless). Maybe that approach can work for you too?

Comment: ah yes, I dont need to store in the db that way , but could be an easy way to compare them. ActiveSupport includes a time.seconds_since_midnight method.

Comment: exactly what I needed.  This guy's a freaking genius.

Comment: I would +100 if I could. Damn genius.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this may not work for days on which daylight savings is an issue, since they do not have the same number of minutes as other days.

Comment: In my concrete case they were used to represent opening hours. The custom getter just took the minutes and converted them to hours and minutes.

Comment: I had a similar situation for storing birthdays without a year.  The solution was very similar: store day-of-year in an integer column.  Dealing with leap years was just as annoying as dealing with a clock change would be in your situation, but it was still the most practical solution.