# ruby adding date 2000-01-01 for column type 'time' in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sequel

how to get only time without date `ruby` + sequel for type `time` in `MYSQL`? ruby adding extra date `'2000-01-01'` with time for `column type` 'time' in MySQL. if the time `'00:01:01'` then ruby giving `'2000-01-01 00:01:01 +530'` in response with sequel.

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you're accessing the data?

Comment: response  = databasename.where([Sequel.qualify(:portalcdrs, :start_time) > starttime], Sequel.qualify(:portalcdrs, :end_time) < endtime, :flowid => flowid).all.map { |h| h.values }

Answer (score 0):

You can't specifically choose to just retrieve the time from this object, but you You can use [DateTime#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to just display the values you need.

```
>> t = Time.now
=> 2015-10-26 09:08:31 +0000

>> t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
=> "09:08:31"
```

It doesn't look like you can eliminate the date element due to the way Ruby deals with time, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359978/represent-a-time-with-no-date-in-ruby).

Comment: but the column type in mysql is only time and the value is '00:00:08'. why it is showing with date like '2000-01-01 00:01:08 +530'. how to t.strftime in sequel response for all columns?

Comment: Do you have the details of the table and columns?

Comment: yes, there is duration column with type 'time' in mysql. i want to apply strftime for all columns.

Comment: my query is 'esponse = databasename.where([Sequel.qualify(:portalcdrs, :start_time) > starttime], Sequel.qualify(:portalcdrs, :end_time) < endtime, :flowid => flowid).all.map { |h| h.values }'. how to apply strftime for duration column.

Comment: result.each { |x| x[:coulmn_name] = x[:column_name].to_f }